# How to Display Data from jsonresult on MVC4 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

How can I display data from jsonresult on my controller to my View?

Please provide steps on how to display it on the view. I'm new to developing MVC4 application.

Here's the code from my Action:

```
public ActionResult IndexChange(string ProposalID)
    {
        PurchaseOrderViewModel po;
        int proposalId = 0;

        proposalId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ProposalID"]);
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["InstitutionID"]);

        List<Institution> lstInstitution = new List<Institution>();

        lstInstitution = db.Institutions.Where(x => x.InstitutionID == ID).ToList();

        List<NewProposal> lstPropospal = new List<NewProposal>();
        lstPropospal = db.NewProposal.Where(x => x.ProposalID == proposalId).ToList();

        ViewBag.Proposal = new SelectList(db.NewProposal.Where(x => x.Status.StatusID == 3), "ProposalID", "ProposalCode");

        var model = new PurchaseOrderViewModel
        {
            Institution = lstInstitution,
            Proposal = lstPropospal
        };

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are sending it as json...directly send this in your view `return View(model)`

import your model in view like this `@model PurchaseOrderViewModel`

Comment: Becauase I have a dropdownlist on the view, once i change selectedindex i need to populate data on the textboxes. I tried to return the model but view wont display the data that I need

Comment: are you doing it by ajax or refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes I used ajax on selectedindexchange and redirect it to another action which will populate the model. But when I tried to return the model, View won't display data.

Comment: url: '@Url.Action("IndexChange", "PurchaseOrder")',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {

                            ProposalID: value

                        },
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (data) {


                           

                            

                        }

Comment: That's my ajax method @Nilesh